# NUnit 3: OneTimeSetUp doesn't fire

Tags: .net, nunit-3.0

In NUnit 3, they've replaced the attribute "TestFixtureSetUp" with "OneTimeSetUp".  However, it doesn't actually seem to work, unless I'm being a complete idiot.

This is my code below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DiskServiceTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IDriveInfoWrapper> _driveInfoWrapper = new Mock<IDriveInfoWrapper>();
    private IDiskService _diskService;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _diskService = new DiskService(_driveInfoWrapper.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetDriveInfo_ShouldReturnDriveInfo()
    {
        // Act
        var result = _diskService.GetDriveInfo();

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

The test will start, but it never goes into Init(), and so _diskService is null.  Am I doing something wrong here, or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NUnit 3.0 is not supported by Resharper. You should install NUnit adapter and use VS to run your tests. That helped me.
More details you can find here
https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1089

Comment: Thanks mate. I wasn't aware that the attribute relied on Resharper to work.  I'll leave the attributes as the `TestFixtureSetUp` ones for now, as it questions whether our build server will be able to run the tests properly.

Comment: +1 That explains why my unit tests passed in Visual Studio but not when run from the console. My `nunit-console.exe` was out of date!

Comment: Welp, now it has been supported but today it randomly decided to ignore the OneTimeSetup once again. Switching to VS' text explorer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the main problem was that the namespace in the main class with [OneTimeSetUp] didn't match the namespace prefix in my test class.

> According SetUpFixtureAttribute documentation: "Identifies a class as
> containing NUnit.Framework.OneTimeSetUpAttribute or
> NUnit.Framework.OneTimeTearDownAttribute methods for all the test
> fixtures **under a given namespace**."

```
namespace Project.Application.SubcutaneousTests;
[SetUpFixture]
public partial class Testing
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
    }
}
```

In the test class I had an incorrect prefix namespace "namespace Project.Application.Common;". I just changed it to "namespace Project.Application.**SubcutaneousTests**.Common;"

```
namespace Project.Application.SubcutaneousTests.Common;
[TestFixture()]
public class MyTests
{
    [Test]
    public void XTest1()
    {
        Debug.Print("Finished.");
    }
}
```

After this, OnTimeSetUp started firing.