# Upgrading Parameterised Webdriver Test to Nunit 3.0

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit-3.0

I was wanting to find a way to repeat failed webdriver tests and stumbled across this http://answered.site/-because-these-are-webdriver-tests-and-not-standard-unit-tests-tests/3612952/. This lead me to the Nunit home page to find they released 3.0. I upgraded frameworks (from 2.4 to 3) and now my solution is not finding any tests. Here is my setup

```
namespace PTTest
{
    [TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
    [TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
    [TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
    public class UnitTest1<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
    {
        PTGeneral General;
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            General = new PTGeneral();
            General.Driver = new TWebDriver();
            General.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
            General.PT_URL = "https://_________________.com/";

        }
        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            General.EmailCleanUP();
            General.Driver.Quit();
        }
```

Now I was looking at the 3.0 documentation of the 'Breaking Changes' and I see they depreciated the [TestFixtureTearDown] and [TestFixtureSetUp]. I changed those spots to the now [OneTimeSetUp] and [OneTimeTearDown] attribute but now when I run my tests it no tests are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry comunity I searched this question before posting but didnt find it till after I made the question. Here is a link to the solution, worked like a charm.
[NUnit 3: OneTimeSetUp doesn't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916416/nunit-3-onetimesetup-doesnt-fire)